# Convert text into binary and add with key using XOR operator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xor

I converted the *text* and *key* from a string to a binary. Now I want to add both lines using the XOR operator.

Example (*Apple* is text and *2* is key; then (*A XOR 2, p XOR 2, p XOR 2, l XOR 2, e XOR 2*).

I am new to C#.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Slovo = textBox1.Text;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (byte b in System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Slovo))
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')).Append(' ');

        string binary1 = sb.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(binary1);

        string Kluch = textBox2.Text;

        StringBuilder sc = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (byte c in System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Kluch))
            sc.Append(Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')).Append(' ');

        string binary2 = sc.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(binary2);

        int a = Convert.ToInt32(binary1); //System.FormatException: 'Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string.'
        int d = Convert.ToInt32(binary2); //System.FormatException: 'Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string.'
        int sum = a ^ d;
        MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to stop using StringBuilder.  After the XOR it is no longer text that can be stored in a string.  Generate a byte[] to get ahead.  How you are supposed to present it is not obvious, review the assignment.  If this is supposed to be real encryption then never use one that is so easy to crack.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you have any solution? Help me please. I am new in C#.

Comment: I have no idea why you need to write this code.  Google "c# encrypt text" to find out how to do it securely and correctly.